# I wrote a program that automatically generates a random room, what's the chance the room will generate the same combination twice?

Tags: probability, random

I've written [this](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/158251324/) program that generates a random room with different obstacles. What is the chance the room will generate the same twice?

Some info:

- The room is 29x23.
- There are 290 objects that can be placed.

Comment: An exact answer requires knowing whether the 290 objects are chosen with or without replacement. Can you put object $5$ in more than one cell?

Comment: how do you decide how many objects go in the room?  if there were 10 objects placed around the room at random, it's already up to a 25 digit number - very unlikely - there are however other questions, such as where does your randomness come from?  Computer random numbers have limited 'randomness'

Comment: In general there should be too much combinations that you can consider removing combinations once they are used,if by some chance you ever run out of combinations just start over (though by my calculations there should be around $10^{196}$ combinations which is enormous.